# Blender 0 weight bones

Tags: bones, unity

Example of the problem: I have 5 objects and 1 armature. Every mesh is skinned to 1 bone and got 1 vertex group, but when I open this ".FBX" in unity and hit 'show all bones', it tells me that every mesh is skinned to every bone what could be the reason for this? I know the problem is in Blender. Opened the ".FBX" in Maya as well and its the same. Tried all kind of exports and cleans and still nothing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did not check, but I know from the past, that Blender FBX exporter is weak and can imagine it adds a 0 weight to non assigned deform weights. Why are the 0 weights a problem?

Comment: lets say that I want this FBX to be separated to 5 or even more prefabs in Unity... I want every mesh-prefab to have only the bones that it needs...It just makes my job easier after that.

Comment: not sure that I follow...what 0 check?

Comment: In unity, check wether the weight associated is 0?

Comment: Its easy to find out which bones control which mesh... I just remember them.. the problem is that I want to delete the bones that do not control the current mesh in the prefab

Comment: I still, completely understand. Hopefully someone will come up with a solution. As a last resort benchmark: it took me about 30 hours to write my own custom fbx exporter using the python fbx sdk. I did because I didn't agree how actions were handled.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option to export only deform bones in the FBX exporter.

[image]

For this to work you must uncheck the Deform option in the bone properties.

[image]

Comment: its not that.... I'm talking about deform bones... I've edited my post with 2 pictures... on the first will see 5 object skinned to 1 armature each object has 1 bone that is skinned to and each object has only 1 vertex group....but on the second one will see this FBX in Unity... and Unity says that every object is skinned to every bone...

Comment: That's working as intended.  When you skin a mesh to a bone it is influenced by every ancestor bone in the hierarchy.  If you dont want this influence, unparent the bone.

Comment: it's not about parenting... its about weight

Comment: I've added a 3rd image ... where you can see an FBX that comes from an other software... and you'll see how every mesh is skinned only to 1 bone... everything that is 0 weight is not shown in Unity and I can easily remove them from the prefab without breaking it...